# Symfony 2.4 expression validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have a problem when adding a validation rule with expression in the validation config file in symfony2. The goal here is to validate if the new password matches the retype new password.
my config is:

```
constraints:
        - Expression:
            expression: "this.passwordMatch()"
            message: "Passwords don`t match"
```

and the function passwordMatch is:

```
public function passwordMatch() {
    if(!empty($this->password)) {
        return $this->password === $this->new_password_confirmed;
    }
}
```

The function is called and its all fine until then. The $this->password and $this->new_password_confirmed are members of the entity, which i created for this form validation, but the values of them come as null. The names of the inputs and of the member variables are the same. Where is my mistake.

I dont use symfony form builder and my form is plain HTML

Hope that i explained the problem good and get an answer soon.

Thanks for the time

Comment: Could you add your FormType code ?

Comment: Well, so can you add your action code please? I can't see how you're mapping your POST data to your entity...

Comment: Stupid mistake ... I have forgotten to map the posted values for these two fields. Thanks your question helped.